# laravel 5 - How can i add ->index() to existing foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Framework: Laravel 5.2
Database: MySQL
PHP: 7.0

I have the table "pops":

```
    Schema::create('pops', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->primary()->index();
        $table->string('ab_test_parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('cloned_parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And the table "conversions":

```
    Schema::create('conversions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->primary()->index();
        $table->integer('users')->default(null);
        $table->string('name',256)->default(null);
        $table->string('pop_id');
        $table->foreign('pop_id')->references('id')->on('pops')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have set a foreign key (pop_id) in the "conversions" table. Now does it's mean that the foreign key (pop_id) is also a index? if not... what i need to do in order to make it a index?

Thank?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP but considering MySQL/SQL you need to add an index explicitly even though you have added foreign key

Answer (score 27):

You can just do this.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddIndexToLeads extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('leads', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->index('trader_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('leads', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropIndex(['trader_id']);
        });
    }

}
```

credit to [@bobbybouwmann](https://laracasts.com/@bobbybouwmann)

Answer (score 6):

I was facing problem when i just write :-

```
$table->index('column_name');
```

So to be more exact first you need to create column with desired column type then assign it to be **index** like this :-

```
  $table->string('column_name');
  $table->index('column_name');
  //or
  $table->string('column_name')->index();
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Here is a perfect solution for you.

**Up**

```
$table->string('poptin_id')->index('poptin_id');
```

**Down**

```
$table->dropIndex(['poptin_id']);
```

**Suggestion to fix your migrations**

```
$table->string('id')->primary()->index();
```

replace above with below

```
$table->increments('id');
```

and fix your foreign key as below

```
$table->integer('poptin_id')->index('poptin_id')->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel only adds a foreign key constraint and doesn't add index implicitly. But some databases such as MySQL automatically index foreign key columns.

If you need to add index to a field in another migration. Then you could do

```
$table->index('email');
```